# Qt is there a way to layout an item in the center of the grid?

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

For example, I have a `QListWidget` named `a` and I only display "thumbnails" of the images under a specified directory. I use `QListWidget::IconModel` to simulate an photo album.

```
a.setViewMode(QListWidget::IconMode);
a.setIconSize(QSize(120, 120));
a.setResizeMode(QListWidget::Adjust);
a.setGridSize(QSize(140, 140));
a.setDragDropMode(QListWidget::NoDragDrop);
```

And the items(`QListWidgetItem`) are set with only icons and tooltips without text, `item->setIcon(QIcon("<image filepath>"));`. But they are not aligned center in the grid. Like this:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xooooooooooooooooooox          x                   x
xooooooooooooooooooox          x                   x
xooooooooooooooooooox          xooooooooooooooooooox
xooooooooooooooooooox          xooooooooooooooooooox
x                   x   ==>    xooooooooooooooooooox
x                   x          xooooooooooooooooooox
x                   x          x                   x
x                   x          x                   x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The outer line `x` is the grid boundaries (140 x 140). And the `o` is an image. Here is a screenshot. The item is on the top of the grid but I want it verticalyl aligned in the middle.
BTW, can I have click event on the grid but not on the item? If an image were too long, its thumbnail would be too small and not easy to click on the item.

[image]